# Listview itemtap executes the same controller function

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have 2 ListView's in my application, when a user clicks on an item of each listview item, the page should navigate to a different view.

In my case, when i click on each views it navigates to the same view. It seems like when the user taps on an item of the view it calls the same controller function. Here's my code, can someone help me solve this;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyCOntroller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {  
            OneList: 'onel',    
            TwoList: 'twol'
        },

        control: {
            "list": {
                itemtap: 'onOnelTap'
            },
            "list": {
                itemtap: 'twolClicked'
            }
        }
    },

    onOnelTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
        console.log("hhhhhh  "+e.event.target.nodeName);
   },

    courtRoomListClicked: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
        console.log(" 2  -- >list");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have not declared your `refs` and `controls` properly.

Let's say your `OneList` has an id called `one-list`, then the refs and controls should be declared like this:

```
config: {
    refs: {  
        OneList: 'one-list'
    },

    control: {
        "OneList": {
            itemtap: 'onOnelTap'
        }
    }
},
```

The rest is okay. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, your `control` configuration is not good and you may need to do like this

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyCOntroller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {  
            // I assume that 'onel' and 'twol' are xtype of respective views
            OneList: 'onel', 
            TwoList: 'twol'
        },

        control: {
            OneList: {
                itemtap: 'onOnelTap'
            },
            TwoList: {
                itemtap: 'onTwolTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onOnelTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
        console.log("onOnel Tap ");
   },

    onTwolTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
        console.log("onTwol Tap");
    }

});
```